# my sidemenu didn't show. I am using "easy_sidemenu" flutter package

Tags: flutter

My sidemen shows for the first time. But when I logout and then came back to dashboard my easy_sidemenu did't show. I have attached the code please review

```
  PageController page = PageController();
  SideMenuController sideMenu = SideMenuController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    sideMenu.addListener((p0) {
      page.jumpToPage(p0);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SideMenu(
            controller: sideMenu,
            items: [
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 0,
                title: 'Dashboard',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                badgeContent: const Text(
                  '3',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                tooltipContent: "This is a tooltip for Dashboard item",
              ),
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 1,
                title: 'Users',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  sideMenu.changePage(page);
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.supervisor_account),
              ),              
              SideMenuItem(
                priority: 2,
                title: 'Logout',
                onTap: (page, _) {
                  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: ((context) =>
                              const Register(screen: false))),
                      (route) => false);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: page,
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I am expecting, sidemenu should display after came back to dashboard. But for now for the first time my sidemenu shows correctly but after navigator my sidebar didn't show

Comment: How do you come back to dashboard from `Register` page?

Comment: Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:
***Caution: You must edit the package file to solve this bug temporarily.***

1. Open `.../easy_sidemenu-<version>/lib/src/side_menu.dart`
2. Replace the `_widthSize` function with this code snippet:

```
double _widthSize(SideMenuDisplayMode mode, BuildContext context) {
  if (mode == SideMenuDisplayMode.open) {
    Global.displayModeState.change(SideMenuDisplayMode.open);
    Future.delayed(_toggleDuration(), () {
      Global.showTrailing = true;
      for (var update in Global.itemsUpdate) {
        update();
      }
    });
    _notifyParent();
    return 250;
  }
  if (mode == SideMenuDisplayMode.compact) {
    if (Global.displayModeState.value != SideMenuDisplayMode.compact) {
      Global.displayModeState.change(SideMenuDisplayMode.compact);
      _notifyParent();
      Global.showTrailing = false;
    }
    return 66;
  }
  return 250;
}
```

*You can change the value `250` and `66` as your need....*

*And, from `SideMenuStyle()`, set `displayMode: SideMenuDisplayMode.open`
....*

**DONE!**

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the "easy_sidemenu" project that has been reported on GitHub. You can stay up to date with the progress of fixing this bug by following the link to the issue: https://github.com/Jamalianpour/easy_sidemenu/issues/31.
The developers are likely working on resolving the issue and this link will provide you with the latest updates.